# How to make the points in google line charts hollow

Tags: charts, google-visualization, linechart

I am using google charts to draw a line chart but i need the points on the chart to have only boundary i.e 'o'
not completely color filled points 
. Can anybody help me with this??. I have used google charts api to draw the line charts.